# Object nested in array who is a property of a class

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the class Map with a property this.guns = [ ]. *I deleted some parts of the code to make it easy to read.*

```
class Maps {
  constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase) {
   this.guns = [];
  }
} // end class
```

Inside `this.weapon = [ ]` I pushed some objects with its properties. Those objects were instantiated in the Map class.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
class Maps {
  constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase) {
    this.guns = [];
  }

  setGuns(quantity) {
    // this.guns = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < quantity; index++) {
      const x = App.random(this.size.x);
      const y = App.random(this.size.y);
      let element;
      if (this.mapGame[y][x] === 0) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0: {
            element = new Gun(4, "watermelon", 15, y, x);
            this.mapGame[element.y][element.x] = 2;
            console.log(element);
            this.guns.push(element);
            break;
          }
          case 1: {
            element = new Gun(5, "eggplant", 20, y, x);
            this.mapGame[element.y][element.x] = 3;
            console.log(element);
            this.guns.push(element);
            break;
          }
          default:
            break;
        }
      } else {
        index -= 1;
      }
    }
    console.log(this.guns);
  }
} // end class
```

I have an other class call Player with a method to move the players. When the player is over a weapon, take the weapon. To do this, I have done the checkWeapon method.

```js
class Player {
  constructor(imagePlayer, name, score, positionY, positionX) {
    this.imagePlayer = imagePlayer;
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
    this.x = positionX;
    this.y = positionY;
    this.movementAccumulator = 0;
    this.limitMovement = 3;
    this.weapon = {};
  }
  
  
/**
 * I deleted the not necessary methods, and then the rest of cases on the switch
 */
  movement(direction, map, currentPlayer) {
    const collision = this.rockCollision(direction, map);
    switch (direction) {
      case up:
        if (this.y > 0) {
          if (!collision) {
            map.mapGame[this.y][this.x] = 0; // draw grass
            this.y -= 1;
            this.whoPlayerIsMoving(map, currentPlayer);
            this.counterMovement();
            this.checkWeapon(map);
          }
        }
        break;
  }

 
  checkWeapon(map) {
    this.weapon = map.getGun(this.y, this.x);
  }
}
```

Player send throung the checkWeapon method the coordinates x and y, to an other method hosted on the class Map, the getGuns method.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
class Maps {
  constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase) {
    this.guns = [];
  }
/**
  * The console log are to render(or print) on the console and look if everything goes well.
  * The following method is a test, is bad done and it have to be refatoriced 
  */
  getGun(y, x) {
    console.log(`Re Y:${y}` + ` Re X: ${x}`);
    console.log(`${this.guns[0].y} ${this.guns[0].x}`);
    if (this.guns[0].y == y && this.guns[0].x == x) {
      console.log("soy un arma");
    }
    return gunTaked;
  }
} // end class
```

My main problem is, how to access to the properties of the Gun object. I did the method above, but I got stuck. I have reading about destructuring, but I am not sure if, should I apply it here. Thanks

I have this

```js
class Maps {
  constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.canvas.width = sizeX * sizeCase;
    this.canvas.height = sizeY * sizeCase;
    this.size = { x: sizeX, y: sizeY, case: sizeCase };
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.tileMap = new Image();
    this.tileMap.src = "img/tileMap.png";
    this.mapGame = [];
    this.FPS = 50;
    this.weapons = [
                    { idWeapon: 2, name: "watermelon", power: 15 },
                    { idWeapon: 3, name: "eggplant", power: 20 },
                    { idWeapon: 4, name: "pumkin", power: 25 },
                    { idWeapon: 5, name: "broccoli", power: 30 }
                    ];
   }
  }
```

The object array isn´t inside the code, I pasted like and example to add more information

Don´t worry by the sintaxis, I am breaking my class in small pieces to don´t paste all the code.

What I want to do, is:  1. find de the objecto I need, It is alredy done, checking the idWeapon

My main problem it is, how to extract the object and hosted in a variable and later if I find an other weapon, let the current weapon and take the new one

Comment: Do you have a fiddle? or any other place where the code is hosted

Comment: What is `gunTaked`? Where did that come from?

Comment: Can you provide some detail about the `setGuns` method?  It looks like it adds at most 2 guns, although it's not clear what `mapGame` is (it could add 0 guns...).  Shouldn't that method add `quantity` guns?

Comment: Given your 2D coordinate system, I'd say you'd be better off storing guns in an object with the `x,y` values as the key, eg `this.guns = {}`... `this.guns[\`${x},${y}\`] = new Gun(...)`. Then when wanting the gun at position `x,y`, you can just `return this.guns[\`${x},{y}\`]`

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh actually it is on Github. I was wondering codepen, but I have more 6 js.